# Work portal (What is this "code")

Tags: apache, administration

I have been a server administrator for the company that I work at, and everytime when I sign in (for the past 3 months) I see this sort of "code" below the portal that I sign into to maintain the website, etc. I decided to ask this question when I was editing our servers apache2 configuration files, etc. I have even asked some of my other colleagues, and they are all about as dumb founded as me! Here it is, "SAMO:181:385:437351712" Does anyone know what that means. If so it would be a great help if you could tell me what it is and why its there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Work portal (What is this "code")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550300/work-portal-what-is-this-code)

Comment: It is a duplicate. Network issues, latency slowed post time. First post try failed. Second time it uploaded, but with a duplicate